# obj[key].newKey = val isn't stored

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to assign a value to an object property but it isn't stored.

```
for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    if (players[i].volume < 1) players[i].volume = (Math.round((players[i].volume + 0.1) * 10) / 10); // JS math error fix
    settings[players[i].id] = settings[players[i].id] || players[i].id;
    settings[players[i].id].volume = players[i].volume;
    console.log(settings[players[i].id] + " " + players[i].id + " " + players[i].volume + " " + settings[players[i].id].volume);
}
```

`settings[players[i].id].volume` == `undefined`

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23yJS/5/)

How can I store the volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add some property dynamically to `settings`, you should first initialize it. Initialization can be done using an empty object literal, like this:

```
settings[player[i].id] = {};
settings[player[i].id].volume = player[i].volume;
```

You wrote:

```
settings[players[i].id] = settings[players[i].id] || players[i].id;
```

that can assign `players[i].id` to the `settings[players[i].id]`, which is not an Object.

You should check the type of `settings[players[i].id]`, then assign something to it:

```
settings[players[i].id] = settings[players[i].id] || players[i].id;
```

Comment: No, I need something like `settings.music.volume == 0.2` and `settings.music.muted == false`

Answer (score 1):

`settings` is an object, so `settings[players[i].id]` is a property of that object with name given by `players[i].id`. You then set this property equal to a string:

```
settings[players[i].id] = settings[players[i].id] || players[i].id;
```

and then try and add a property to it:

```
settings[players[i].id].volume = players[i].volume;
```

which won't work because it's a string. There's no error because the browser will temporarily wrap the string in an object wrapper, which is then instantly disregarded.
You're doing something similar to this:

```
var string = "something";
string.prop = 10;            // won't throw error
console.log(string.prop);    // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `settings` is an array, meaning that you should use only 0 based integers as keys. In this example you are attempting the following:

```
settings[players[i].id]
```

This can only work if `players[i].id` is an integer and that all indexes start from 0 and so on.

If you want to store arbitrary keys, then don't declare `settings` as an array. Declare it as an object:

```
var settings = { };
```

Now you can store arbitrary properties:

```
settings['foo'] = 'bar';
```

But if you declare it as an array:

```
var settings = [ ];
```

Then you can only use:

```
settings[0] = 'foo';
settings[1] = 'bar';
...
```

Comment: It is already an object. `settings[players[i].id]` == "music"

Comment: Yes, but how did you declare the `settings` variable? As an array or as an object?

Comment: Object, check the first line in the Fiddle

Comment: It would also work if `settings` were an array, nothing prevents you from adding additional properties to an array. You shouldn't do that but an array is an object too, so it works.